# Cohomology for affine open maps

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a affine, open, surjective, finite map between projective varieties.
Is it true that, for any $i \ge 0$, $H^i(X,\mathbb{Q}) \cong H^i(Y,\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: No, this is not true. For example, take any non constant map $E\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve, and recall they don't have isomorphic $H^1$. By the way, a finite map is always affine, and if the target is irreducible, it is also surjective.

Comment: Dear @ Roland:  no, a finite map with irreducible target needn't be surjective. Think of $\operatorname { Spec} k\to \mathbb A^1_k $

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg You are right of course. I thought about the extra assumption that the map is also open, but forget to add it in my sentence. (Open and finite with connected target is surjective)